# PDF.Js doesn't load PDF file

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I have downloaded PDF.Js from Github. I changed the

**var DEFAULT_URL = 'http://www.krishnamraju.com/downloads/web/krishnam.pdf';** in viewer.js in Web Directory.

But when I open **http://krishnamraju.com/downloads/web/viewer.html** I can see the PDF container with tools but the PDF does not load in to it.

Can you please help?

Comment: Dead link. Please edit your question with a link to your real demo page (preferably include the relevant file structure and/or code snippets).

Comment: Sorry @RobW I have amended the links. Please check.

Comment: You have to use `node make.js generic web`, and copy the output of `build/generic` to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a relative path. Use this:

**var DEFAULT_URL = 'krishnam.pdf';** as both the pdf and viewer.js sit in the same folder.

Or even a better solution is to use '?file' param as a dynamic path to pdf's look [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2496) for more information.